# VSCode C# ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

### VSCode C# ввод с клавиатуры

Доброго времени суток.Моя проблема состоит в том ,что я не могу открыть свой код с помощью терминала и ввести значения или посмотреть результат.На этом сайте я нашёл решение проблемы

> Нужно параметр ***console*** установить в значение ***externalTerminal***

но оно работало не долго.И теперь vscode ругается на меня,помогите пожалуйста,что мне надо сделать чтобы всё работало?

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    },

    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
 ,]
```

}

[image: launch.json error]

Comment: Э-э-э... В `program` так и записано: `<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>`? Или там реальный путь, а вы заменили его, выкладывая сюда?

Comment: Я тоже не разобрался в этом.Я думал попытаться поменять путь,но не знаю куда у меня он установлен .И когда менял  **project-name.dll** на имя самого проекта то ничего не поменялось.
Или мне надо там прописать путь самого проекта?

Comment: Гляньте в репозитории, какое значение там было раньше. Ах, вы не используете систему контроля версий? Тогда бросаете все другие дела и прям щас принимаетесь за изучение, скажем, git.

Comment: Хорошо,пойду гляну.Спасибо!

Comment: Ну откройте папку `bin/Debug/` в папке своего проекта. Если оно раньше работало, то там будет папка с именем фреймворка, а в ней - предыдущая dll.

Comment: Заработала!!!Большое спасибо!